# Latex custom list with tocloft is causing line breaks

Tags: tocloft

I have used the `tocloft` package to create a custom list of abbreviations. The layout in the list if fine. The problem that I have it that the command to create this entry creates a linebreak and I was after inline inclusion of the abbreviation.

The relevant code defining the list of abbreviations, as well as packages and a minimum of the preambule is as follows:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[extendedchars, babel, multidot]{grffile}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, array}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listabrevname}{Liste des abréviations}
\newlistof[chapter]{abreviation}{abrev}{\listabrevname}
\newcommand{\abreviation}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{abreviation}%
    \par\noindent\textnormal{#2  (#1)}%
    \addcontentsline{abrev}{abreviation}{%
        \protect\numberline{}#1 -- #2%
        }\par%
}
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{abreviation}{0em}{0em}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.00em}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.00em}
\setlength{\cftbeforeabreviationskip}{1.0em}

\begin{document}

%a bunch of stuff%

\addtocontents{abrev}{\noindent\textbf{Abréviation}~\hfill\textbf{Première Apparition}\par}
\listofabreviation
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hphantom{\numberline{\thesection}}\listabrevname}%
\newpage

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Liste des figures}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hphantom{\numberline{\thesection}}\listfigurename}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\noindent\textbf{Figure}~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\newpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hphantom{\numberline{\thesection}}\listtablename}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\noindent\textbf{Table}~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\newpage

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\hbox{}\par}
\tableofcontents

\newpage

chapter{Introduction}\label{Intro}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

The use of \abreviation{HA}{Acide hyaluronique} represents...

\end{document}
```

This gives:

---

.......Some text and some more text and some more text `%line break - indented`

Acide Hyaluronique (HA) `(No indent)`

.......The continuation of the text on yet another line... `indented`

---

I am looking for a continuous insertion of the abbreviation, so no linebreaks, which would give:

---

Some text and some more text and some more text Acide Hyaluronique (HA) Th continuation of the text on the same line.

---

I have tried introducing `~` to prevent a break, as well as the `\nobreak`, `\nolinebreak` at various places in the definition but have had no luck so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I don't understand why you want to glue one abbreviation appearance after another one the same line? How should this fit with the page of the first appearance then?  I think you would get a better performance with packages like `acro`, `acronym` or `glossaries`. `\addcontentsline` causes new lines.

Comment: You have  `\par`s in there which you don't want. This lets the abbrv.  start a new paragraph at the beginning and the end of the abbrv.. Apart from that, you are reinventing the wheel. See the packages in the previous comment.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks. it was the \pars - I didn't know they always generated new paragraphs. While these other packages are probably very effective. given i'd already defined other lists, this was more or less a copy paste minus this small issue. I also didn't want to end up with problems defining the way each title appears as I currently have 4+ `\titleformat` sections for each type of title. Feel free to post a proper answer so I can accept it, and any more détails about the way \par works would be appreciated for the future.